# Remote data store processing with ElasticSearch 7.1 and log4j2.11.1

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am using ElasticSearch 7.1. It comes with log4j2.11.1.jar. The problem comes when I am trying to setup a remote data store with log4j2 running as a TcpSocketServer. I would then use log4j logging API in different Java applications to transmit logs over to the remote data store to analyse. However, from log4j2 Java documentation, I found out that the TcpSocketServer has been taken out.

How did you guys managed to configure a remote data store with the latest log4j2 library? Is there any working architecture layout which still fits my use case?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch is not a great log shipper; also what happens if the network is down? We're generally going more down the route that the Beats should take that part over, so Filebeat with the Elasticsearch module here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.1/filebeat-module-elasticsearch.html